# Does Javascript have Java's Calendar helper class?

Tags: java, javascript, calendar

i'm trying to use the Java version of:

```
Date d = new Date(2010, Calendar.AUGUST, 28);
```

but in Javascript:

```
var d = new Date(2010, ???, 28);
```

i cannot find a helper class that contains month constants? Does the Java helper `Calendar` class exist in Javascript?

Comment: Eh... nope. Define your own constants.

Comment: And for clarity, there is no relation between java and javascript except for the name.

Comment: Ah, there is another relation between the two: the stupidity of counting months starting from 0. That’s why Java has constants for the months.

Comment: @andred +1. i lost four hours this morning trying to figure out such non-sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is not Java.
Fortunately, there are libraries like [`datejs`](http://www.datejs.com/).

> Datejs is an open-source JavaScript Date Library.
>
> Comprehensive, yet simple, stealthy and fast. Datejs has passed all trials and is ready to strike. Datejs doesn’t just parse strings, it slices them cleanly in two.

For an example, see the [`set()` method](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#set):

> `set`
>
> `.set ( Object config ) : Date`
>
> Set the value of year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond of date instance using given configuration object.

```
// returns Jul 15 2008 18:45:30
Date.today().set({millisecond: 500, second: 30, minute: 45, hour: 18, day: 15, month: 6, year: 2008});
```

Comment: i'm using `datejs`. It's great for `.addDays`. Javascript, on the other hand, makes me want to kill someone.